# React - re-rendering when data has changed on the server but no props have changed

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

I have a component that contains a list of items for an order. Currently the only prop for the component is the order id, and the component is responsible for fetching the list of items into state and displaying them.

Now if another component adds or changes an item in the order, I want to re-render the list of items but without changing the order id.

The usual approach seems to be to have a bogus prop which is just a nonce that the parent can change when the component needs to refresh, and the component uses `if (prevProps.nonce != this.props.nonce)` in the `componentDidUpdate` method.

It works fine but I don't like the fact I'm having to use what looks like a bodge for such a straightforward case. I realise there are other alternatives like calling `forceUpdate()` but again the documentation advises against using it.

Should I lift the state up to the parent, even though no other components care about the list of items? That seems the most React-ish way to do it but I don't like the way it breaks the OO encapsulation principle.